# Ajax call wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

come in a bit of problem trying to call my function in wordpress ajax.. This is what i have so far if any one can point me in the right direction that would be super...trying to pull my artist feed through an ajax call using a function in my custom.php file im using the ajax functionality in Wordpress for the url

thanks

```
Custom.php
<?php

function enable_ajax_functionality() {

wp_localize_script(' ajaxify ', ' ajaxify_function ' , arrary(' ajaxurl ' => admin_url (' admin-ajax.php ') ) );

}

add_action(' template_redirect ', 'enable_ajax_functionality');

function test_ajax() {

header( "Content-Type: application/json" );

$args = array(
'posts_per_page'   => 5,
'offset'           => 0,
'category'         => '',
'orderby'          => 'post_date',
'order'            => 'DESC',
'include'          => '',
'exclude'          => '',
'meta_key'         => '',
'meta_value'       => '',
'post_type'        => 'artist',
'post_mime_type'   => '',
'post_parent'      => '',
'post_status'      => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true );

$posts_array = get_posts($args);
echo json_encode($posts_array);
die();
```

}

```
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_test_ajax" , 'test_ajax');
add_action("wp_ajax_test_ajax" , 'test_ajax');

Ajax Call


function getFeed() {

    console.log(ajaxURL);

    jQuery.ajax({
     url: ajaxURL,
     data: ({action : 'test_ajax'}),
              success: function( response ){
                console.log( response );
            }

         });

}
```

Comment: remove the header line, it's not necessary

Comment: nope still didnt work... keep getting a 0.. not sure what else try

Comment: just to test : what do you get if you replace you echo by this
echo json_encode( array(
  'message' => "it works"
 ) );

Comment: still get 0! im calling the function correct :S

Comment: Fixed it put my php in my functions.php thanks for your help

Comment: On your `wp_localize_script()` you have mis spelt array.